# Bus Stop Schedule

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-places-api, google-directions-api

I'm having some trouble retrieving some information about the bus stop schedule of a single bus stop.

Basically, when I open the bus stop on google maps, I can see all bus lines for that stop and it's respective schedule time.

[image]

After clicking on `see departure board`:
[image]

However, I couldn't find a way of getting this information from the google maps api.
I tried searches by place_id and geographic coordinates and I was able to find some information about this stop, but not lines or schedule times..
I saw some people being able to find some information like this by setting a route on the directions API, but in my case I need the complete schedule of the bus stop itself, and not the info between two locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid Google doesn't expose this sort of information via their Google Maps APIs at the moment. There is a feature request in the Google issue tracker to make this information available (33 stars currently, however doesn't look like priority at Google as FR was opened in 2015):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827961

Feel free to star the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications from Google.